# Free Component which can show richtext with pictures Delphi

Tags: delphi, image, richtextbox, components, richedit

I need a free component like RichEdit, but which can also show pictures inside. I am using Delphi 7. Unfortunately RichEdit cannot show pictures, and few components which can are not free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [Jedi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/) Components, they have enhanced RichEdit component, There's one called JvxRichEdit(Came from RxLibrary), which can show pictures.

[image]

You can find how to display the picture above [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1332)

Answer (score 0):

JvRichEdit does this, and is included as part of the Jedi project.